# Date format for timestamp in WebMethods

Tags: datetime-format, webmethods

I am trying to create Event Timestamp as per the below format:-
`2021-04-05T06:39:33.931-07:00`

I tried using the below pattern for the same:
`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ`

Unfortunately, the output is not the same. Below is the output for the same:
[image]

Can you please suggest what should be the correct pattern for this?
Below is the code block where I am putting the inputs:-
[image]

Comment: The `+0000` strongly suggests that it's not merely the format that's going wrong, but also that your timestamp has no time zone information. If that is *constant* (that is, you are OK with UTC timestamps) you can simply use a hard-coded `+00:00` in the string. If not, you'll also need to look at how you're getting the timestamp.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert , So, I tried setting the time zone (as PST) and below is the output I am getting: `2021-05-25T08:43:08.553-0700` .  Is there any way to make this as : `2021-05-25T08:43:08.553-07:00`. The pattern I am using is : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern for a time zone with a colon: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

WebMethods `pub.date:getCurrentDateString` uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

From the [Java 1.8 Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (adapted to fit the question):

| Letter | Date or Time Component | Presentation | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Time zone | ISO 8601 time zone | -07 |
| XX | Time zone | ISO 8601 time zone | -0700 |
| XXX | Time zone | ISO 8601 time zone | -07:00 |